# AWS EC2 websocket over https ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, websocket

I'm having trouble getting my websocket to work over HTTPS.

When I'm on localhost and connect to it over http (and change the node.js server back to http) everything works fine.

However in production, I can't connect to it over HTTP due to Mixed Content issue, and when I change the node.js server to https and the websocket url to https I get the following error:

> https://ec2-35-166-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lj0QXtq net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

obviously, my node.js server on AWS' EC2 instance doesn't have an SSL certificate so how do I get my web socket to work with a site running on https?

I also tried replacing `https://` with `ws://` as I saw suggested somewhere but that results in the same as HTTP does and get's blocked.

Here's my node.js code to set up the socket:

```
var app = express()
var https = require( "https" ).createServer( app )
var io = require( "socket.io" )( https )
https.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0")
```

Here's how I connect to it on the client's side:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min'
let socket
let socketURL = 'https://ec2-35-166-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080'
...
socket = io.connect(socketURL)
```

For the sake of trying to make this work, I set my Inbound security groups to allow all traffic from anywhere. So that shouldn't be an issue. I also tried to specifically allow all HTTPS traffic from anywhere.

I also tried changing the https.listen to port 443, and removing :8080 from the websocket url. Still same error.

I get absolutely no response headers or anything back from the server (I am assuming it doesn't even make it that far as it can't find an SSL certificate for the AWS server), but it leaves me with absolutely no idea how I can debug this.

How can I connect to my websocket on AWS from an https website?

Do I actually have to buy and set up a second SSL certificate just for the server?

Comment: Have you tried the secure websocket protocol wss://?

Comment: @stdunbar I just tried that, still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it did require an SSL certificate. After purchasing and setting up one, the https works completely fine.

Comment: Where did you end up hosting the pems? Is it possible to host them on S3 or some other server not on AWS?